# Bundle firebase-messaging-sw.js deps with Webpack

Tags: javascript, firebase, webpack, service-worker

Say I have a file in which I initialize Firebase and import its dependencies.

**app.js**

```
import firebase from 'firebase'

firebase.initializeApp()
```

Now I want to reference the same dependencies for **firebase-messaging-sw.js** as well but since it needs to be in the root, how can I tell Webpack to solve the dependencies?

Sure enough I could go with

```
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.1.3/firebase.js')
```

But that would download me the code twice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This plugin solved my problem. firebase-messaging-sw.js will be copied to root folder after building production

```
let config = {
  plugins: [
   ...,
    new CopyPlugin([
      {
        from: 'firebase-messaging-sw.js',
        to: 'firebase-messaging-sw.js'
      }
    ])
  ]
}
```

If you have more than 1 service worker file with different environments. It can be like this

```
let config = {
  plugins: [
   ...,
    new CopyPlugin([
      {
        from: isProduction ? 'firebase-messaging-sw-prod.js' : 'firebase-messaging-sw.js',
        to: 'firebase-messaging-sw.js'
      }
    ])
  ]
}
```

Comment: I'm getting an error saying "'must NOT have additional properties. (to)"

Answer (score -1):

Not 100% clear on what you're trying to do, are you trying to treat a script that you load remotely as a webpack dependency? Webpack's standard module-building assumes that the modules you import are all local files available at build time. To treat a remote script as a dependency, I would recommend defining it as an `external` dependency in webpack: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/externals/

In this example of an `externals` config (taken from the linked docs):

```
externals: {
  jquery: 'jQuery'
}
```

... you would reference the jquery library with `import jquery from "jquery"` (using the key you specified in `externals` config). At runtime, webpack will look for a global var named `jQuery` (the value for that key in your `externals` config). Webpack takes no responsibility for actually loading the dependency in this case, it assumes the global you specified will already be defined at runtime -- which is why they're called "external" dependencies -- so you would have to load the dependency (the firebase library) separately before your webpack bundle.